# Генерация звука

Tags: ассемблер

Здравствуйте.

Недавно задали написать программу, генерирующую определенную частоту звучания, зависящую от нажатия клавиш на клавиатуре. Клавиатура должна содержать не менее двух октав звуков на ассемблере i8086. Ничего в голову не приходит, даже как начать программу.

Помогите, пожалуйста. Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1):

```
.286
.model small
.stack 20h
.data

.code

sound proc 
    pusha
    ;mov di,6000   ;частота звука
    ;mov bx,2000   ;длительность
    mov al,0b6H
    out 43H,al
    mov dx,0014H
    mov ax,4f38H
    div di
    out 42H,al
    mov al,ah
    out 42H,al
    in al,61H
    mov ah,al
    or al,3
    out 61H,al
    l1:     mov cx,2801H
    l2:     loop l2
    dec bx
    jnz l1
    mov al,ah
    out 61H,al
    popa
    ret
sound endp

start:
    mov di,500 ;     загрузка частоты звучания динамика
    mov bx,2000;    загрузка длительности звучания в тактах м/п
    call sound

    mov di,1000 ;     загрузка частоты звучания динамика
    mov bx,2000;    загрузка длительности звучания в тактах м/п
    call sound

    mov di,1500 ;     загрузка частоты звучания динамика
    mov bx,2000;    загрузка длительности звучания в тактах м/п
    call sound

    mov ah,4cH
    int 21H

end start
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за код.Только еще один вопрос я ее запустил но ничего не проигывает.и никаких сообщений не выводит просто загружается и сразу исчезает.интересно почему?( запускал через Фар.

Comment: Наверное, потому что это ДОС программа и требуется прямой доступ к оборудованию?

Comment: Все может быть просто другие программы написанные на ассемблере нормально запускались и делали все что было задано..

Comment: Так вы определитесь, на какую платформу надо

Comment: Ассемблеров очень много разных =) И код для PC будет сильно отличаться от кода для какого-нибудь ARM Cortex-M3.

Comment: Так написано же - i8086. Насколько мне известно, на i8086 ниче кроме ДОСа не запустить. ELKS - не в счет.

Comment: А, не заметил =) Раритет, однако. Ну запустить там что-то можно, но скорее всего это, и правда, дос - обычные учебные задания редко отличаются извращённостью и нестандартными условиями вроде какой-нибудь давно устаревшей и позабытой ОС =)

Comment: Убрал процедуру asbin, которая ни откуда не вызывается, переменную T, которая нигде не заполняется, и вообще все содержимое секции `.data`.